# AngularJS $http.post return status 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, http-headers

I'm working on Ionic framework's angular js. And when I request the data, it always return the status 0 as the error. I believe the issue is HTTP access control (CORS). But I already set **Access-Control-Allow-Origin as ***. What do I need to do more? Please help. Thank you.

Angular JS Code

```
var params = {
         limit: 5,
          page: 1
       };

$http.post('https://www.example.com/getdata.php', { params: params })
.success(function (data,status) {                        
        console.log("Conection available . Status s" + status);                         
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error Status " + status);
});
```

Return Header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Access-Control-Request-Headers → *
Access-Control-Request-Method → POST
Cache-Control → max-age=2592000
Connection → Keep-Alive
Content-Length → 1933
Content-Type → application/json
Date → Thu, 08 Sep 2016 06:47:31 GMT
Expires → Sat, 08 Oct 2016 06:47:31 GMT
Keep-Alive → timeout=5, max=100
Server → Apache/2.4.20 (Ubuntu)
```

UPDATE

---

So the actual error code from browser log is

**XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.example.com/getdata.php. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.**

And I tried updating Access-Control-Allow-Headers header as the following.

```
 $http.post('https://www.example.com/getdata.php',
                        { params: params },
                        { 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'application/json' })
```

And updated the respond header as the following.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Headerss → application/json
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Access-Control-Request-Headers → *
Access-Control-Request-Method → POST
Cache-Control → max-age=2592000
Connection → Keep-Alive
Content-Length → 1933
Content-Type → application/json
Date → Thu, 08 Sep 2016 07:22:03 GMT
Expires → Sat, 08 Oct 2016 07:22:03 GMT
Keep-Alive → timeout=5, max=100
Server → Apache/2.4.20 (Ubuntu)
```

But still no luck. Please help.

Comment: What error does the browser report in the console?

Comment: I do not see any error except the logs I added for error function as like"
 log      Error Status 0"

Comment: Oh Sorry. I checked it emulator. In browser it is "Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response."

Comment: I guess your server needs to send `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header while sending the response back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` doesn't support wildcards. You are using `*` but must specify the allowed headers explicitly.

---

> And I tried updating Access-Control-Allow-Headers header as the following.

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is a **response** header. You have to set it on your server, not your client.

Your client side JavaScript cannot give itself permission to read other people's data. That would make having the requirement to get permission pointless.

Comment: Thanks.. I finally make it after changing the header into "Access-Control-Allow-Headers → Content-Type" in the respond. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try to put exactly domains in Access-Control-Allow-Origin,  I also saw same issue
And add whitelist plugin for cordova to your project

For Android Simulator use 10.0.2.2

Comment: But, I'm requesting it from the android simulator. Which domain should I put for this?

Comment: Are you developing an ionic app?

Comment: Yes. I"m developing Ionic App.

Comment: 10.0.2.2 for android emulator